# Is veth layer 2 or layer 3 device?

Tags: networking, veth

[Veth](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html) device pairs allow creation of a virtual ethernet tunnel on a linux system. I want to ask whether a veth device should be considered a layer 2 or layer 3 device ?

Based on my understanding veth device is assigned a MAC address and can also be assigned an IP address for routing, so it is a layer 3 device then ?

Answer (score 2):

veth interfaces are layer 2 devices.  As you mentioned, you can also create IP addresses on both sides of the veth tunnel pair.  The IP address provide layer 3 connectivity.  If you happen to do something interesting with those veth tunnels and their IP addresses, like SSH between them, or run a web server / whatever, those services will operate in the OSI model's 4-7 layers.